# Can I limit the zoom feature in desktop browser inside a range?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I limit zoom in desktop browsers? 
For mobile browser, I use meta viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

For desktop browsers, I want to limit zoom from 100% to 300%. Searching on Stackoverflow, I have found a solution to prevent zoom using JavaScript or jQuery blocking the CTRL key. This is not exactly what I want.
I just ask a crossbrowser solution which allows the user to zoom, of course but inside this range: 100% - 300%.
How can I do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Set maximum-scale to 3

Comment: @Terry the CSS Device Adaptation Module should make that possible, however most browsers are not implementing it fully yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport meta tag was introduced by apple to make responsive design more easier, later most browser vendors started handling this tag. However the viewport meta tag is not part of any web standards, the maximum-scale controls how much a user can zoom, and while it works for most browsers on mobile, it does not work for desktop browsers.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=3" />
```

If u use this tag, users wont be able to zoom more than 300% on mobiles, however on desktops they are not limited.

The [CSS Device Adaptation Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#atviewport-rule) introduced viewport rules which should allow u to control zoom and max-zoom and min-zoom of the viewport. However this is still in a working draft state.

The following should be a cross-browser solution, and according to [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/max-zoom#Browser_compatibility) it should be working on chrome but actually it is not.

```
@viewport {
  zoom: 1;
  max-zoom: 3
}
```

Ironically chrome is actually handling the zoom rule correctly, but its discarding the max-zoom in browsers.

Anyway in practice it's not a really good idea to limit users from zooming, if u think big zooms are causing a certain page to look extremely ugly u can handle that using media queries.

But if u are really desperate, what u could do is to override the shortcut for zooming in desktop browsers, and change the document base zoom level yourself. While this works it would be an ugly hack and u have to handle different shortcuts based on different Operating systems/browsers, not to mention that if a user has a custom shortcut mapping your hack will not work.